# What is the oem-dell-he-esxi module?

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell

I'm attempting to use the vSphere Update Manager for the first time to do an ESXi 4.1 to ESXi 5.0 upgrade.

The server shipped with Dell's ESXi pre-installed, and when I attempt to do an upgrade to ESXi 5, I get the following prompt:

[image: Software modules oem-dell-he-esxi published by third party vendor(s) are installed on the host. Upgrading the host will remove these modules]

> Software modules oem-dell-he-esxi published by third party vendor(s) are installed on the host. Upgrading the host will remove these modules

I've googled high and low, but I can't find any reference to what on earth that module is, and what I will lose if I remove it in order to do the upgrade.

Does anyone know what the `oem-dell-he-esxi` module is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dell CIM provider modules for ESXi, nice to have if you want to monitor the host, and be able to see all of it's hardware specs and statuses in the ESXi console, and also remotely connect to it using IT-Assistant

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that's the hardware management module for OpenManage.

We got a special DELL-branded ESXi install media from DELL that included the custom drivers.

Contact your service rep and see about that.